# Django как связывать два поля

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

У меня есть модель `Car`, внутри нее есть два поля `mark` и `model`, которые реализованы с помощью `choieces`. Значение моего второго поля зависит от выбора первого. Как мне все это реализовать лучшим образом для удобства?

Я использую Django, Django REST на серверной части, Vue CLI на клиентской. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Естественно на сервере в модели/форме перед сохранением проверять что все верно.

В клиентской части можно при изменении первого поля запрашивать данные для второго поля и обновлять их, или вывести в шаблон зависимости полей в виде JS объекта или как вы используете в vue.js.

Можете заменить choices на модели, тогда это будет более расширяемо и удобнее, так как правки в списке моделей и марок не придется править прям в коде

Comment: Не сможете на примере показать ?